# Installing stained glass in a shower wall

Tags: shower

I need a stationary window in a shower wall to allow maximum light into the shower.  A want to install a stained glass window in the dry side of the shower and a safety glass pane on the wet side.  I have several ideas but please offer suggestions.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"Stained glass" window film is a thing. Gives you the look of stained glass without the risk of breakage. Use your favorite search engine to find a pattern that will pass a lot of light.

Comment: I feel there's just something ineffably sad about having a plastic film trying to look like stained glass… having said that, my 'wooden' kitchen floor is plastic-coated particle board, so I'm not going to ring the taste police ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you already own this stained glass panel?
Can we assume it's a 'real' leaded glass?

You can get them fully encapsulated inside double glazing [at a price, of course] - can't touch it any more, but it will give it a good life extension. I have some here I wanted preserving in new window units. Of course, you cannot use it as one pane of a regular sealed unit, it can't take the pressure.

Perhaps you could get a sealed unit made up with zero pressure? then at least you can treat it as a single unit. [that's something I've never investigated].